# How can I access salesforce as a remote data source?

Tags: azure, salesforce, datasource

How can I access salesforce as a remote data source?  I want to write an Azure service that processes information held in a salesforce org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Force.com Toolkit for Azure](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-For-Windows-Azure). See also [Getting Started with the Force.com Toolkit for Azure](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Toolkit_for_Azure)

Comment: Thanks, looks like a great place to start.